# Xcode Storyboard issue - Button Bar Button only appears at the bottom of a TableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Not sure if this is a bug in Xcode 6(I use Beta 4) or expected behaviour.

When I have a View Controller in a Navigation Controller and 'push' (deprecated segue) a Table View Controller(TVC) I can drag a Bar Button Item to the Navigation Bar in the TVC.

[image]

When I do the same but 'show' (new adaptive segue) the TVC, the Bar Button Item drops to the bottom, and in fact doesn't show up when I build the project.

[image]

A hack to resolve this problem is to set it up as 'Push' to begin with, drag on the Bar Button Item, and then change the segue to 'Show'. But - is this necessary? Is this an Xcode Bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you for that little 'hack'. I was having the same issue... I'm not sure why it does this and I cannot find any explanations. Nonetheless, your solution helped me so thanks!

Comment: Same problem, so it is really a bug ?

Comment: The 'hack' to use deprecated Push and then switch back to Show worked for me as well. thanks!

Comment: this should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have tried creating the issue you are facing with bar button at bottom. It’s not an issue or Xcode bug.
    But in new Xcode when you use segue to ’Show (e.g. Push)’ then in next view you won’t get navigation bar.
[image]
    You need to add navigation bar and then add bar button item to navigation bar.
[image]
[image]
Hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: Great answer, my only criticism is that it looks as though you're actually dragging on a 'Navigation Item' rather than 'Navigation Bar'. Makes sense, seems as though 'Push' added a Navigation Item by default and 'Show' does not.

Comment: Push adds navigation bar by default but if you want to make change in navigation bar button from storyboard you can do by this way. You can make custom back button and left/right buttons programmatically. I've tried doing it in storyboard using xcode 6 but was facing this issue so found this solution by using storyboard. But making change in navigation bar programmatically i would recommend. As you can see that there was no navigation item in Title viewController but was in ViewController.

Comment: So you need to add navigation item in Title viewController else if you try to add bar button it will be added in toolbar at bottom of view controller.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.
Adding Navigation Bar, then adding navigation item worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and fixed it by simply selecting the view controller and changing the "Top Bar" to "Opaque Navigation Bar" from Inferred. This let me add the Bar Button Item on top.

Comment: I did this too and it let me place a BarButtonItem on the top-right.  Why on earth does this work?  My guess is that the top right/left 'Items' are transparent, while the parent VC's right/left Items can draw through to those spots.  That is why programmatically you can set those Items to barbutton's, but that is still setting the parent's Items.  By setting the child's to opaque, you can set them directly.  However, this is just a theory that seems reasonable to me, and not based on direct evidence.  Would love to know whats really happening.